# How to create sound from an array of double and play it on speaker

Tags: c++, c, linux, audio

I have an array of double (size more than 60k entries), I have the frequency value. Now I want to create a sound from it using C/C++ which I can play on speaker. My OS is linux.

Thanks. I hope I am clear enough.

Comment: I'm assuming the `double` values are simply the amplitudes, and not some compressed (MP3-like) representation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6735

This is a link to an article in Linux Journal about programming with the ALSA (Advance Linux Sound Architecture).  It contains some example code.

Answer (score 2):

The following information comes from a command-line program called `beep`, available in Debian. The source code is available through the repositories, and also available [here](http://johnath.com/beep/beep-1.2.2.tar.gz).

There's an `ioctl()` call with a KIOCSOUND request to the console device that you can use to play sounds through the PC speaker. The snippet is:

```
ioctl(fd, KIOCSOUND, CLOCK_TICK_RATE/(int)frequency);
```

to play a sound with frequency `frequency`, and:

```
ioctl(fd, KIOCSOUND, 0);
```

to stop the beep. `fd` is a file descriptor with write permission to `/dev/console`, and `frequency` is the sound frequency, given in hertz. The constant CLOCK_TICK_RATE is related to a timer chip used to create the beep, and in the `beep` source code has the value 1193180 (hertz). Although this might be different for your system, if my mind is correct, I do remember have seen this same constant on old DOS programs that used the PC speaker.

Answer (score 1):

The Qt library may be overkill for what you want to do and there may be an easier option but it's **an** option :)

You should be able to use the [QAudioOutput](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qaudiooutput.html#details) class to do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Two other api's to look at would be SDL and SFML.